# Which of the two is correct, please?

Tags: grammar

> "Will the new plane be heavier? I wish **it weren't**. "

or

> "Will the new plane be heavier? I wish **it won't**. "

*Thank you.*

Comment: Neither... "I hope it won't."

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. You use the word 'wish' to talk about a hypothetical situation, for example "I wish I were rich". Is that the kind of thing that you want to say?

Comment: No, JavaLatte, I want to say I don't want this to occur in the future, so I'll follow TypeIA's construction. Thank you both!